# Converting Milliseconds String to formatted date String in SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, adapter

I'm retrieving a milliseconds `String` from my `SQLite` database and want to convert it to a formatted date `String`. It basically works, but not when I'm trying it in an array (see below). It throws a `NumberFormatException`. How can i fix this?

```
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listrow, cursor,
        new String[] { getDate(Long.parseLong(Database.KEY_DATE), "dd. MMMM yyyy hh:mm:ss") , Database.KEY_NAME },
        new int[] {R.id.text1, R.id.text2}, 0);

public static String getDate(Long milliSeconds, String dateFormat){
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
}
```

Comment: What is `Database.KEY_DATE`? I suspect the problem is when you're trying to parse it, although all the calendar stuff is a longwinded way of writing `new Date(milliseconds)`

Comment: Database.KEY_DATE retrieves a milliseconds String.

Comment: It retrieves that millisecond `String` AFTER the `Cursor` runs. At present, you are trying to make a `Long` out of the value of `Database.KEY_DATE`.

Comment: @user1617102: Are you sure about that? Are you sure it's not *the name of the column in the database*? That's not the same thing at all. (It seems unlikely that a *field* - named as if it's a constant - can somehow retrieve a value.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't parse it out until after the value is returned from `new SimpleCursorAdapter`. This means you need to create your own `SimpleCursorAdapter` type and override `setViewText`.

Something like this:

```
adapter = new MySimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listrow, cursor,
        new String[] { Database.KEY_DATE , Database.KEY_NAME },
        new int[] {R.id.text1, R.id.text2}, 0);

// ...

public static String getDate(Long milliSeconds, String dateFormat) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    return formatter.format(milliSeconds);
}

// In MySimpleCursorAdapter.java:

public class MySimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    @Override
    public void setViewText(TextView v, String text) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.text1) { // Make sure it matches your time field
            // You may want to try/catch with NumberFormatException in case `text` is not a numeric value
            text = WhateverClass.getDate(Long.parseLong(text), "dd. MMMM yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        }
        v.setText(text);
    }
}
```